# How Do I Make A Picture Grow (HTML/Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

Hope this message finds you well. I'm working on an assignment where they want me to make a particular image grow upon pressing a button that says grow (by using an html file and JavaScript file), but I've been hitting a wall for over an hour on this. Any advice?

Here's what they gave me:

```
<button id="button1">Grow</button>
```

I tried doing the following:

### .html file (Option #1, failed):

`````````
  ````width: 350px;
  ````height: 100px;
  ````display: -webkit-flex;
}

````#button1:nth-of-type(1) {-webkit-flex-grow: 1;}

</style>

.html Option #2, failed: 
------------------------------------------------
````<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>


.html Option #3, failed:
---------------------------
<script>
````document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", ````myFunction);

````function myFunction() {
  ````document.getElementById("button1").style.height="250px";
}
</script>

______________________________________________________________________
.js file (Option #1, failed): 
------------------------------------------------
````document.getElementById("button1") 
````````.addEventListener("click") .style.height="250px";


.js file Option #2, failed:
--------------------------------
````div:nth-of-type(1) {flex-grow: 1;}


.js Option #3, failed: 
--------------------------------
````object.onclick = function(){myScript};


.js Option #4, failed:
------------------------
````object.addEventListener("click", myScript);




I thought that at least one of these options would lead to the following:

The image would grow upon clicking the "Grow" button, which is what I'm trying to do.
`````````

Answer (score 2):

As your description says you need an image but from your code examples you are trying to resize button.

This simple code below binds click event listener to a button and whenever you click it makes image width to 250px.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector('img').style.width = '250px';
};
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Grow</button>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPDlQ.png" width="100">
```

Comment: Sadly didn't work - original code: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>
    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>
    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>
 </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: What do I need to do to get the box + button 1 to grow when I click on the button 1? Thank you @harry!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding Style to the button on clicking it, not to image

Html

```
  <img src="../Img.png" id="ImageId" style="width:200px">
  <button onclick="BiggerImage()">Click</button>
```

Js

```
  var Image = document.getElementById("ImageId");
  function BiggerImage(){
     Image.style.width = "400px";
  }
```

Comment: I am confused (thank you so much for helping, btw!) - the button isn't an image, just a button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out it might help. Cheers

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JavaScript Increasing and Decreasing Image Size</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function zoomin(){
            var myImg = document.getElementById("sky");
            var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
            if(currWidth == 500){
                alert("Maximum zoom-in level reached.");
            } else{
                myImg.style.width = (currWidth + 50) + "px";
            } 
        }
        function zoomout(){
            var myImg = document.getElementById("sky");
            var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
            if(currWidth == 50){
                alert("Maximum zoom-out level reached.");
            } else{
                myImg.style.width = (currWidth - 50) + "px";
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <button type="button" onclick="zoomin()">Grow</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="zoomout()">Shrink</button>
        </p>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476718840318-386693801fbe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" id="sky" width="250" alt="Cloudy Sky">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Question: how would this be coded without an img src? Also, with a zoomout/zoomin, does that mean that the button would grow AND shrink?

Comment: Yes zoom in and zoom out are grow AND shrink here, I will update my answer again.

Comment: We need to give image src as we wanted an image to Grow right?

Comment: Correct - we want an image to grow, but I need "button1" to ONLY make the image grow, not grow and shrink.

Comment: You can avoid using shrink button by removing that button in html

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'm going to try this - fingers crossed!

Comment: It didn't work - I think it's because they provided a box, not an image, for the assignment:  ````  <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>

Answer (score 0):

WAIT! Everyone! My friend helped me figure it out! For the .html, it's:

```
    <button onclick="growpicture()" id="button1">Grow</button>
```

FOR .JS IT'S:

```
     function growpicture(){
            document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
```

}

Cheers, thank you all so much for the help!!!